# Fitting a function with R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nls

I want to fit a function to these data:

```
s <- c(20:60)
I <- c(0, 0.007515662, 0.015878514, 0.024994325, 0.034728341, 0.044910579, 0.055344590, 
       0.065818599, 0.076118441, 0.086040566, 0.095403934, 0.104059903, 0.111898792, 
       0.118853016, 0.124896650, 0.130041857, 0.134332925, 0.137838655, 0.140644404,  
       0.142844161, 0.144533652, 0.145804788, 0.146741667, 0.147418108, 0.147896553, 
       0.148228057, 0.148453067, 0.148602679, 0.148700131, 0.148762313, 0.148801181, 
       0.148824980, 0.148839256, 0.148847645, 0.148852473, 0.148855195, 0.148856698, 
       0.148857511, 0.148857941, 0.148858164, 0.148858276)
```

The plot is the following:

[image]

I tried using `nls` as follows:

```
mod <- nls(I~exp(a+b*s), start=list(a=0, b=0))
```

but I think I got a bad fit.

This is the fit I got by nls method with these initial parameters:

```
(RSS.p <- sum(residuals(mod)^2))  # Residual sum of squares
(TSS <- sum((I - mean(I))^2))  # Total sum of squares
1 - (RSS.p/TSS)  # R-squared measure
0.611088
```

[image]

I am interesting in finding an expression for a function with parameters, not only in a good graphical fit (because then I want to treat this function analytically).

Comment: because it seemed to me like a "mirror" exponential.. But probably it is a wrong assumption

Comment: What are `I` & `s`? Is there any theoretical reason to think the functional form is of one type or another? (Also, it isn't clear to me that this is an R coding question.)

Comment: `f <- approxfun(s, I); plot(s, I); lines(s, f(s), col = 2)`

Comment: Thanks rawr! The thing is that I do not only a plot, but I want the parameters of this function (because then I want to treat it analytically). That's because I thought nls was a good method to use.

Comment: @CrishaD The residual standard error t is nothing more than the positive square root of the mean square error. It's **NOT** the R-squared.

Comment: Please see this for calculating R-squared: http://robinlovelace.net/2013/10/23/nls-demonstation.html

Comment: @CrishaD Well, IMO, your assumption was not incorrect, you could achieve a similar form if you i.e. modify your original model to ``nls(I ~ c - exp(a+b*s), start=list(c = 0.15, a = 0.4, b = -0.1))``. It's not a perfect fit, you could try adding some additional parameters, though now with a negative sign before the exponent and a constant term it becomes similar to exponential CDF, so it has the property to converge to a constant value (``c`` actually), just as your data implies.

Comment: An ordinary nonlinear logistic fit should probably work pretty well

Answer (score 4):

You could try adding a constant term `c` and a negative sign to your original equation, plus an additional squared term, as suggested by other answers:

```
mod <- nls(I ~ c - exp(a + b*s + d*s^2), start=list(c = 0.15, a = 0.4, b = -0.1, d = 0))
```

to obtain such fit:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will solve this first with `nls` and then show even better solutions with `glm`. Finally I will come back to `nls` and show an even higher fit, but which may be *overfit*.

```
mod <- nls(I~exp(a+b*s+c*s^2), start=list(a=0, b=0, c=0))
summary(mod)

yhat <- predict(mod,I,type="response")
plot(I,col="green")
lines(yhat, col="blue")
```

[image: nls]

```
(RSS.p <- sum(residuals(mod)^2))  # Residual sum of squares
(TSS <- sum((I - mean(I))^2))  # Total sum of squares
1 - (RSS.p/TSS)  # R-squared measure
```

> 0.910058

This GLM fits even better:

```
mod <- glm(I~s+I(s^2))
```

McFadden R-squared is about .981

Here's the plot:

```
predict <- predict(mod,as.data.frame(s),type="response")
plot(predict)
```

[image]

We can perhaps make it a little better:

```
mod <- glm(I~s+I(s^2)+log(s))
```

McFadden R-squared is about .990

The far end of the plot starts to level off a little more, as in the actual data this way:

```
predict <- predict(mod,as.data.frame(s),type="response")
plot(predict)
```

[image]

I used the package `BaylorEdPsych` to get McFadden's psuedo R-squared.

Finally, using `nls` this model had the highest fit of all, but it may be overfit:

```
mod <- nls(I~exp(a+b*s+c*s^2+d*I(1/s)), start=list(a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0))
summary(mod)

yhat <- predict(mod,I,type="response")
plot(I,col="green")
lines(yhat, col="blue")
```

[image: nls]

```
(RSS.p <- sum(residuals(mod)^2))  # Residual sum of squares
(TSS <- sum((I - mean(I))^2))  # Total sum of squares
1 - (RSS.p/TSS)  # R-squared measure
```

> 0.9972944